# Microsoft Translator API Error Message: The received token is of incorrect token type

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-translator, azure-marketplace, bing-translator-api

I am getting 400 error message as shown in image below, when I try out the Translation API using Try it out link [http://docs.microsofttranslator.com/text-translate.html](https://portal.azure.com/#dashboard/private/a8a4033c-f69f-4a8b-87a4-151efef1a00d)

I am using the  Access Key generated from Azure Portal for Cognitive Services Free trial.

[MS Azure Portal Link](https://portal.azure.com/#dashboard/private/a8a4033c-f69f-4a8b-87a4-151efef1a00d)

I have read on MS support blogs and I tried all the suggestions mentioned in them. But everytime, I get the 400 Status error as shown below. 
Can someone please help me to resolve this issue??

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get an access token first (docs [here](https://docs.microsofttranslator.com/oauth-token.html)) by doing a POST request:

```
curl --header 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: <YOUR-API-KEY>' --data "" 'https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken'
```

And then use that token in the `Authorization` header. (`appId` has been deprecated).

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/xml' --header 'Authorization: Bearer <YOUR-TOKEN>' 'https://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/http.svc/Translate?&text=this%20is%20my%20name&from=en&to=af'
```

Comment: No, you can't do that call from the browser because it's a POST request. You should use a tool like Postman. https://www.getpostman.com/

Comment: Also, please edit your comment and delete your subscription key!

Comment: maria, the issue token call worked now...It returned a very long key...I took the key and added it in the Authroization Header in following URL:https://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/http.svc/Translat?&text=this%20is%20my%20name&from=en&to=af.....But it gives error, Status 0:no response from server..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145404/discussion-between-sabyasachi-and-maria-ines-parnisari).

Comment: Ah, there's a typo in the URL... it has to be `/Translate`, not `/Translat`... my bad, sorry

Comment: It works now!...Here is the response I am getting : <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">これは、私の名前</string>

Answer (score 0):

You can use Microsoft Translator API in 2 ways ([see the docs](http://%20%20http://docs.microsofttranslator.com/text-translate.html)):

- in 1 step: invoke (GET) https://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Http.svc/Translate?text=Neoliberismo&from=it&to=en, passing `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: your_subscription_key` as request header
- in 2 steps, with OAuth:

  - invoke (POST) https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken, passing `Subscription-Key=your_subscription_key` as query parameter or better passing `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: your_subscription_key` as request header
  - you'll get a token that expires after 10 minutes
  - invoke (GET) https://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Http.svc/Translate?text=Neoliberismo&from=it&to=en, passing `Authorization: Bearer the_token` as request header